# Adding multiple entries to my mysql table with one query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add multiple entries to my mysql table with one query. This is my query:

```
$ophours = "INSERT INTO stores_op_hours(Store_Id,Day_Name,Open_Time,Close_Time)
    VALUES 
    ('$stid','mon','00:00','23.59'),
    ('$stid','tue','00:00','23.59'),
    ('$stid','wed','00:00','23.59'),
    ('$stid','thu','00:00','23.59'),
    ('$stid','fri','00:00','23.59'),
    ('$stid','sat','00:00','23.59'),
    ('$stid','sun','00:00','23.59')
    ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $ophours);
```

And I try to catch any errors like this:

```
if (!mysqli_query($link,$ophours))
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error with inserting to db ". mysqli_error($link)."')</script>";

    }
```

No error is showing, but also, the data isn't added to the db

Comment: Please share you full code. Without it, we cannot understand the issue.

Comment: Is Store_Id is unique key in your schema ? If not, then your query looks perfect. check your mysql connection by a simple select query.

Comment: Connection is fine, I'm using the connection for another query which executes perfectly. Store_id is not the PK for this table, it's a FK from a different table tho @AnkitAgarwal

Comment: echo the `$ophours` in browsers & post it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your `$link` is working (from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php)) :

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
```

Otherwise try a `space` after your `stores_op_hours (`

It could be the time field I don't know if `12:34` or `12.34` is allowed try instead `12:34:56`.

Comment: db link is working, another query goes through. And the fields where the time goes are varchar

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the database "layout".
I'll try to test it on my own and see if I get any errors.

Comment: I just tested it and it worked fine for me.
Are you using int,varchar,varchar,varchar as fields?

Make sure that the Store_Id field is **NOT** unique.

My code:
`$link = mysqli_connect("1.1.1.1:3306", "user", "pw", "db");
$stid = 5;
$ophours = "INSERT INTO stores_op_hours(Store_Id,Day_Name,Open_Time,Close_Time)
    VALUES 
    ('$stid','mon','00:00','23.59'),
    ('$stid','sun','00:00','23.59')
    ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $ophours);`
 Worked for me.